# Angular momentum and energy conservation for a given Hamiltonian

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, conservation-laws, hamiltonian-formalism

Assume that the evolution of a system is defined by a Hamiltonian $H$ given by
$$
H= a \,\mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{p}  + b  \,\mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{q}  + c  \,\mathbf{q} \cdot \mathbf{q}.
$$

Here $a,b,c$ are constants and $(\mathbf{p} , \mathbf{q})$ are the usual generalized coordinates of the phase space.
How do I show that the Hamiltonian $H$ is conserved during the evolution? How about angular momentum?

Comment: Since this Hamiltonian has no explicit time dependence, you can show that it is conserved using [Hamilton's equation of motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_bracket#Hamilton's_equations_of_motion) written in terms of the Poisson bracket.